# Executing a number of CPU-using and Network-using async methods simultaneously in .NET

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task, cpu-usage, bandwidth

My project is an html parser, that parallel loads html pages with a number of HttpClients(one client for each proxy in my list) and then parses loaded html pages with HtmlAgilityPack(third-side library for html parsing).

This method loads page using HttpClient. So it uses a network, low CPU usage:

```
LoadObjectPageAsync(client, i)
```

And this method parse loaded page. Doesn't use network, uses much CPU:

```
ParseObjectPageAsync(i)
```

In my project I simultaneously execute a number of this async method for each proxy in my WebProxy list:

```
    Private Async Function LoadAndParseAsync(ByVal _proxy As WebProxy) As Task

    Dim client As HttpClient = CreateProxyHttpClient(_proxy, 10000)

    For i = 0 To URLS.Length - 1
        Await LoadObjectPageAsync(client, i)
        ParseObjectPageAsync(i)
    Next

End Function
```

Each HttpClient loads page by page, and after each loading complete I start parsing task for this page and forget about it.

My internet channel bandwidth is 30 Mbps. Here is a download speed diagramm during this method execution (I can't post images cause of low rating):

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2ebae4n.jpg

CPU using ~ 50-60%. But in this case internet channel doesn't always fully loaded during execution.

And If I execute above method without this string:

```
ParseObjectPageAsync(i)
```

(so i just don't parse loaded pages), then I've got this:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/rmu5gn.jpg

CPU using is about 5-10%. But bandwidth fully loaded. That's what I want to see with parsing.

So, when I call ParseObjectPageAsync(i) method, I expect, that It will have no affect on network using. But it somehow affects, in spite of the CPU is not fully loaded during execution, only 50-60 percent. So parse tasks interrupt load tasks. That's what I want to fix, cause the main priority is a maximum using of internet channel.

Maybe there is a way to set the priority of Parse tasks to low. Or other way to solve the problem.

I can read both VB and C# code. Sorry my bad English.

**UPLOAD:**
The **ParseObjectPageAsync** method is:

```
Private Async Sub ParseObjectPageAsync(ByVal _num As Integer)

   // Await is a first keyword, so the whole method 
   // must run asynchronously, as I expect.
    Await Task.Run(Sub()

                           // and here some proccessing with loaded page.

                   End Sub)


End Sub
```

Comment: Provider throttling? Or maybe target website limits number of simultaneous connections or total bandwidth from a single user?

Comment: What does ParseObjectPageAsync do? If it takes a long time the network will be idle during that time.

Comment: **NeolisK**, the problem appears just when ParseObjectPageAsync(i) added. In other cases, pages load as expected. So it's not ISP or website limit issue. **usr**, ParseObjectPageAsync(i) is Async Sub, so It starts as a new task so parent method (LoadAndParseAsync) continue to execute. Or I missing something?

Comment: Well, if `ParseObjectPageAsync` is defined as `Thread.Sleep(1000)` you'll block the caller. The "first part" (for some definition of that) of an async method runs synchronously.

Comment: @usr, ok, i get it. But if my method begins from Await keyword, so it must be fully async, right? Take a look at the upload pls.

Comment: Yes, this is safe because there is no potentially blocking code left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mixing asynchronous and CPU-bound work, I recommend [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). You can set up a basic pipeline where the first `TransformBlock` takes URLs and (asynchronously) downloads them, and the second `TransformBlock` does the parsing. Then you can adjust the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option for both blocks as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it if there will be no another solution.

Comment: I made first steps in understanding TPL Dataflow. Now I'm trying to realize the pipeline. As I already said, I load HTML pages throw number of proxies. Should I create a TransformBlock for each proxy and then link them all to one parse TransformBlock? Can I contact you by your email?

Comment: It's best to ask questions on SO. I think one block per "operation" would be appropriate, so if a response was "follow this proxy", you should have a loop in your mesh with a filter.

Comment: Stephen, I realized it with TPL Dataflow. Btw in my case many TransformBlock for each Proxy gave better results then one block with deside which proxy to use in it. Bandwidth usage graph more smoothly. And everything works well, CPU works, Bandwidth fully used. Great library. Thank you again.